# How does f := x * fact(x-1) work?

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, oracle11g

```
declare
    num number;
    factorial number;

    function fact(x number)
       return number
    is
       f number;
    begin
       if x=0 then
          f := 1;
       else
          f := x * fact(x-1);
       end if;
       return f;
    end;

begin
    num:= 6;
    factorial := fact(num);
    dbms_output.put_line(' Factorial '|| num || ' is ' || factorial);
end;
/
```

How does `f := x * fact(x-1)` work? Like a loop or something?

Comment: I edited the title of your question to include the code you're calling, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it.  Also, I improved formatting and removed tag not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a *recursive function*, i.e. it calls itself. As you can see, you declared it (`FUNCTION fact`), and then - in its body - it calls the same FACT function (`fact(x-1)`).

So, yes - it looks like some kind of a *loop*.

In order to find out how it works, take a piece of paper and follow its execution. Use x = 3 (that will be enough), write down value of the F parameter, step by step, and you'll see what it does. Someone might do that for you, but that wouldn't help much. I presume it would be better if you find it out yourself.

Comment: if i use 3, does it looks like this 3*2*1*1?

Comment: Try it, and you'll know it.

Comment: @SurfaceTension yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

you have declared the function `FUNCTION fact(x number)` and you are calling the same function from inside it `f := x * fact(x-1);`. This is called as recursion and is similar to a regular `loop` in this case but `recursive` approached are more powerful especially when we have more the one paths to take in the next iteration.

One can view this mathematically in a directed call graph.

```
A - - - |
^       |
|       |
|       |
 - - - - 

FUNCTION A()
    A();
```

see [tutorial](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html) which explains Recursion clearly. Note that syntax is in `C++`.

Comment: You could have posted **source** from which you took that *drawing* as the author, I suspect, is not you (but http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html)

Comment: Well, it uses syntax of `C` and I didn't want to confuse the person who asked the question. Anyway, yes I took the drawing from there. Just wanted to be as informative as I could.

Comment: It is not about *being informative*, but *being fair* as well.

Comment: You can't imagine how happy I am right now! Thanks a million!